# MoveModifire Help in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I' m new in andengine. I have a question regarding movemodifier method.

I have successfully moved a sprite using MoveModifier method from one point(x=0) to another point(x=100).

Can I stop the sprite before reaching to the target point(x=100) and then restart the sprite from where it was stopped ?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all your response. I solved my problem using

PhysicsHandler handler = new PhysicsHandler(sprite);

sprite.registerUpdateHandler(handler);

handler.setVelocity(x,y);

instead of MoveModifier method.

When the car collides with any moving objects coming from top to bottom of the screen then I use ( handler.setVelocity(0,0);) .Because of this the moving objects are stopped.
And now after few seconds when car is not in the objects way I reset the velocity using handler.setVelocity(x,y); so now the objects start moving from where it was stopped.

Comment: This solution may not be entirely correct. With setVelocity(x,y), you do not have pixel control which you do with the MoveModifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you are looking for, but the easiest way to do that is to use two MoveModifiers - one to get the first spot, then when ready to go the rest of the way, use a new MoveModifier.

It really depends on your needs - if they as simple as you stated, then 2 MoveModifiers would work - I suspect however that you have more demanding needs that we are not aware of.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm developing a car race game in which some objects are moving from top to bottom using MoveModifier method and if any one of them collides with user car then all the moving objects should stop and after few seconds objects should move again.

Comment: how are you determining when a collision happens? Might help if you post your code.